# Value not incrementing

Tags: c

A value that is to be incremented with `++` does not work in a certain scenario.

I have a project that uses the [C Unity Testing Framework](https://github.com/ThrowTheSwitch/Unity).

This library implements a function that is called when running a test, and [will increment a value during this](https://github.com/ThrowTheSwitch/Unity/blob/master/src/unity.c#L1831).  The value that should be incremented is `Unity.NumberOfTests`.

However, that value is not incrementing.  Even though the `Unity.NumberOfTests++` is being executed.

I can confirm stepping through with gdb:

```
Breakpoint 2, UnityDefaultTestRun (Func=0x1fd9 <mytest>, FuncName=0x2bf4 "mytest", FuncLineNum=32)
    at ./lib/unity/unity.c:1831
1831        Unity.NumberOfTests++;
(gdb) explore Unity.NumberOfTests
The value of 'Unity.NumberOfTests' is of type 'UNITY_UINT' which is a typedef of type 'unsigned int'
'Unity.NumberOfTests' is a scalar value of type 'unsigned int'.
Unity.NumberOfTests = 0
(gdb) n
1832        UNITY_CLR_DETAILS();
(gdb) explore Unity.NumberOfTests
The value of 'Unity.NumberOfTests' is of type 'UNITY_UINT' which is a typedef of type 'unsigned int'
'Unity.NumberOfTests' is a scalar value of type 'unsigned int'.
Unity.NumberOfTests = 0
```

as you can see, `Unity.NumberOfTests` is `0` before *and* after `Unity.NumberOfTests++`.  I am unsure why.  What are the scenarios that would case a variable, particularly a member of a structure, to not increment?

More details:

- this is a program that is compiled with the [gnu arm embedded toolchain](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm)
- this program is compiled for [Qemu](https://www.qemu.org/), and executed on Qemu, emulating a cortex-m4 processor

Comment: What optimization level are you using when compiling?

Comment: Hey @SteveSummit, I haven't specified any optimization during compilation. I do use the -g flag, and since I used that, I believe that turns optimization to 0?

Comment: same thing if you `print` instead of `explore`? Same thing if you `printf` the value there instead of step through with gdb?

Comment: Hey @yano, I just confirmed.  Yes and yes.  Same thing if I use `print` and same thing if I add a check in the source code and run it similar to `printf`

Comment: error in the library. Raise the issue on github

Comment: hey @0___________, I raised it here https://github.com/ThrowTheSwitch/Unity/issues/580 I wanted to make sure this wasn't something obvious I was missing in C first

Comment: It cannot be answered easy without seeing your code (or rather full project). You may have error in your linker script and place this variable in the FLASH memory for example. Embedded programming is significantly different comparing to the "normal" computers one

Comment: @0___________ I wanted to undelete this because you were right.  My linker script was placing this variable into flash memory.  When I changed it to place it in RAM, it worked.  I wanted to give you credit for that answer if you want: checking to make sure the variable is stored in a memory address whose contents can be changed by the program during execution.

Comment: @northsideknight 